# Data fetch using OData API in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, odata

I an new in iPhone.Currently i am working on OData based web service. But i am little confusing with how to call webservice and getting response with OData.I have below information with me.

The metadata of this service is located at : 
http://enumbler.azurewebsites.net/odata/$metadata

and Base url is :: http://enumbler.azurewebsites.net/odata/User

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with IOS, but I may help with common way to consume OData services. Take one OData sample service [TripPin](http://www.odata.org/blog/trippin-new-odata-v4-sample-service/), if you want to get all airlines, you can simple calling http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/Airlines. The response is in JSON payload, you can consume this either directly dealing with JSON or use some OData client libraries for IOS. One difference your service and the sample service has may be that TripPin is OData V4 and your service is OData V3. Maybe your service doesn't support JSON but ATOM payload, but you can deal with either way I mentioned above. For more detailed information of OData, you can go directly to [OData.org](http://www.odata.org). Hope I helped you with part of your problem.

Comment: Hello sir,I have Odata web service but how to call  it in ios

Comment: @user3879130 You can use odata client lib for IOS like http://odataobjc.codeplex.com/  to consume odata services.

Comment: I use this library but i doesn't understand there are product class ,category class

Comment: Sorry, not understanding your comments " there are product class ,category class". Again, I'm not familiar with IOS, https://github.com/OData/OData4ObjC/tree/master/Sample there are samples and hope they can help.